# Unable to login Google SSO in superset

Tags: oauth-2.0, single-sign-on, apache-superset, google-sso

I have installed superset in docker and tried to implement **Google SSO in superset**. I tried to follow the official docs "**Custom OAuth2 Configuration**" from https://superset.apache.org/docs/installation/configuring-superset/ . I changed my configuration here at `superset_config.py` file. According to the information provided,I added my configuration here:

```
    # Set the authentication type to OAuth
    AUTH_TYPE = AUTH_OAUTH
    
from custom_sso_security_manager import CustomSsoSecurityManager
CUSTOM_SECURITY_MANAGER = CustomSsoSecurityManager


    OAUTH_PROVIDERS = [
        {   'name':'google',
            'token_key':'access_token', # Name of the token in the response of access_token_url
            'icon':'fa-address-card',   # Icon for the provider
            'remote_app': {
                'client_id':'clientIdfromCredintials',  # Client Id (Identify Superset application)
                'client_secret':'clientsecretfromCredintials', # Secret for this Client Id (Identify Superset application)
                'client_kwargs':{
                    'scope': 'email profile'               # Scope for the Authorization
                },
                'access_token_method':'POST',    # HTTP Method to call access_token_url
                'access_token_params':{        # Additional parameters for calls to access_token_url
                    'client_id':'clientIdfromCredintials'
                },
                'access_token_headers':{    # Additional headers for calls to access_token_url
                    'Authorization': 'Basic XXXX'
                },
                'api_base_url':'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/',
                'access_token_url':'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token',
                'authorize_url':'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth'
            },
            'request_token_params': {
                    'response_type': 'code',
                    'scope': 'email profile'
                }
                
        }
    ]
```

For this parameter value as provided in official docs:

```
'access_token_headers':{    # Additional headers for calls to access_token_url
                    'Authorization': 'Basic Base64EncodedClientIdAndSecret'
                },
```

I created `base64 encoded value` from https://www.base64encode.org/ with combination of **clientidsecretid.**

I also created `custom_sso_security_manager.py` file and put it under same directory of `superset_config.py` file. I added below lines of code:

```
import logging
from superset.security import SupersetSecurityManager

class CustomSsoSecurityManager(SupersetSecurityManager):

    def oauth_user_info(self, provider, response=None):
        logging.debug("Oauth2 provider: {0}.".format(provider))
        if provider == 'google':
            # As example, this line request a GET to base_url + '/' + userDetails with Bearer  Authentication,
    # and expects that authorization server checks the token, and response with user details
            me = self.appbuilder.sm.oauth_remotes[provider].get('userDetails').data
            logging.debug("user_data: {0}".format(me))
            return { 'name' : me['name'], 'email' : me['email'], 'id' : me['user_name'], 'username' : me['user_name'], 'first_name':'', 'last_name':''}
```

I used these url's while generating `clientid` and `clientsecret`. Is there anything wrong I did?

[image]

In the official docs redirect url needs to be given as:

```
The redirect URL will be https://<superset-webserver>/oauth-authorized/<provider-name>
```

I even added redirect url as below and it was not working. The error was same:

```
http://localhost:8088/superset/welcome
```

The `Google SSO` page opens when I goto **url**:
[image]

After entering `username` and `password`, I get this page:

[image]

I am getting `Invalid login.Please try again` error. Do I have misconfigured anything for Google SSO?

My `localhost` is running using `http://` rather than `https://`

Answer (score 0):

You might be doing too much.  The docs say:

> **Beyond FAB supported providers (GitHub, Twitter, LinkedIn, Google, Azure, etc)**, its easy to connect Superset with other OAuth2 Authorization Server implementations that support “code” authorization...

Google is a FAB supported provider, so I don't think you need `CUSTOM_SECURITY_MANAGER = CustomSsoSecurityManager` or your `custom_sso_security_manager.py` file.  What happens if you run it just with the code:

```
 OAUTH_PROVIDERS = [
        {   'name':'google',
...
```

from the [FAB Security documentation](https://flask-appbuilder.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security.html#authentication-oauth)?